# Plotting graph in a same figure for two different values of parameter

Tags: plotting, visualization

Here I am trying to plot the graph for two different values of the parameter `m`, say `m=5` and `m=10` in the same figure. I have tried with `Show[Plot1,Plot2]` and `Show[Graphics[Plot1,Plot2]`. However, it is showing some errors and doesn't produce any figures.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
a = 0.5;
b = 2.0;
t = 0.0;
Q0 = 1.0;
alp = 0.5;
alpha = 0.5;
beta = 1.0;
k = 0.5;
m = 5.0;

ph[h_, F_] := 
  Block[{sol}, 
   sol = NDSolveValue[{s''[y] == (m/alpha)*Sinh[alpha*s[y]], 
      p''''[y] - (1/k)*p''[y] + beta*m*m*s'[y] == 0, s'[0] == 0, 
      s[h] == 1, p[0] == 0, p''[0] == 0, p[h] == F, p'[h] == 0}, 
     p'''[y] - (1/k)*p'[y] + (beta*m*m*s[y]), {y, 0, 1}]];
xi = Range[0, 1, .02];
hi = Map[1.0 - (a*Cos[Pi*(# - t)]*Cos[Pi*(# - t)]) &, xi];

ph0[h_, F_] := 
 Block[{sol}, 
  sol = NDSolveValue[{s''[y] == (m/alpha)*Sinh[alpha*s[y]], 
     p''''[y] - (1/k)*p''[y] + beta*m*m*s'[y] == 0, s'[0] == 0, 
     s[h] == 1, p[0] == 0, p''[0] == 0, p[h] == F, p'[h] == 0}, 
    p'''[0] - (1/k)*p'[0] + (beta*m*m*s[0]), {y, 0, 1}]]

Fi = Range[-3, 3];
Fdp = Map[{#, 
     NIntegrate[
      ph0[1.0 - (a*Cos[Pi*(x - t)]*Cos[Pi*(x - t)]), #], {x, 0, 
       1}]} &, Fi] // Quiet
ListPlot[{Fdp, Fdp}, AxesLabel -> {F, dp}, Joined -> {True, False}]
```

Comment: Shouldn' t the functions depend on `m` too? Where is the code with definition of `plot1,plot2,...`? In your pervious question I gave  several hints how to answer this question. You seem to ignore them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One last assist:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
a = 0.5;
b = 2.0;
t = 0.0;
Q0 = 1.0;
alp = 0.5;
alpha = 0.5;
beta = 1.0;
k = 0.5;
m =.;

  

    ph0[h_, F_, m_] := 
     Block[{sol}, 
      sol = NDSolveValue[{s''[y] == (m/alpha)*Sinh[alpha*s[y]], 
         p''''[y] - (1/k)*p''[y] + beta*m*m*s'[y] == 0, s'[0] == 0, 
         s[h] == 1, p[0] == 0, p''[0] == 0, p[h] == F, p'[h] == 0}, 
        p'''[0] - (1/k)*p'[0] + (beta*m*m*s[0]), {y, 0, 1}]]

Fi = Range[-3, 3];
mi = {1, 5};
coli = {Blue, Red};
Show@Table[
  Fdp = Map[{#, 
       NIntegrate[
        ph0[1.0 - (a*Cos[Pi*(x - t)]*Cos[Pi*(x - t)]), #, 
         mi[[k]]], {x, 0, 1}]} &, Fi] // Quiet;
   ListPlot[{Fdp, Fdp}, AxesLabel -> {F, dp}, Joined -> {True, False},
    PlotStyle -> {coli[[k]], coli[[k]]}],
  {k, 1, Length[mi]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I will not post anything associated with this issue further.